# How can I make a button to reduce and opposite layouts on android studio?

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, android-layout, button

How can I configure this button to reduce and opposite layouts in android studio

[image: example of the button]

Comment: Could you please explain this in more detail? I don't understand what you mean at all.

Comment: I want to set the button clickable and if I click on it ,it opposite other layouts for the same product cause if I mate for every product a layout, the drawable will be tall. so if there is a possibility to program this button it will be a good solution

Comment: helloo ! is that possible

Comment: How should I know? I still don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: I mean I want to make some layouts hide .but if when the  button clicked the layout that hidden turn visible